# Mostrar un archivo bmp en consola en java

Tags: java, linux, imagen

Debo de mostrar un archivo bmp en imagen

Esto es lo que llevo pero solo muestra archivos txt

```
import java.io.*;

public class BMPImageHandler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length >0){
            try{
                String filename = args[0];
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Leimos del archvio "+ line);           
                
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Error! el archivo no existe");
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error! Ocurrio un error en la lectura del archivo");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error, no dio el nombre del archivo en los argumentos");
        }
  
    }
}
```

Y tambien debo de rotar las imagenes 180 grados del eje X y Y

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en qué sistema operativo estás? en cual de todas las consolas que soporta ese sistema operativo?

Comment: @RuslanLópez estoy trabajando con replit, seria linux

Comment: hasta donde yo se, en replit no se pueden mostrar imágenes en la consola, lo que si puedes hacer es leer una imagen y generar otro archivo de imagen con la modificación y al hacer clic el archivo puedes ve la imagen, pero durante el proceso de ejecución del programa java no se puede hacer, esta restriction no es solo de java sino de los lenguajes que no se están ejecutando en un entorno grafico, para eso necesitas un aplicación en swing o javafx.

Comment: @Roberto E Moran Muchas gracias, he estado probando y logre crear otro codigo logrando hacer una copia del programa estoy haciendo una modificación para poder girar la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta es excesivamente amplia y lo que has implementado es prácticamente nada.
Aún así te dejaré el algoritmo base para que lo implementes a pesar de que es una cantidad descomunal de trabajo por si te animas a implementarlo... ya sabes... por los jajas.

La consola de repl.it es parcialmente compatible con [xterm](/questions/tagged/xterm), por lo que puedes usar los mismos códigos para imprimir a color.

[image: terminal de repl.it con colores]

Para ello hay 3 valores que debes de poner junto coon la secuencia de escape ansi /033, por ejemplo

```
\033[31;1;4m
```

que deberían de corresponder a color de texto, resaltado y formato

Para ello puedes hacerte un menú para probar todos los valores posibles para que veas cuales están soportados algo así

```
private static int chooseStyle() {
    System.out.println("Choose your style");
    String[] fontEffect = new String[]{"normal", "negrita", "deslavado", "Itálica", "subrayado", "parpadeo simple", "parpadeo rápido", "inverso", "conceal", "tachado", "fuente1", "fuente2", "fuente3", "fuente4", "fuente5"};
    for (int i = 0; i < fontEffect.length; i++) {
        String string = fontEffect[i];
        System.out.printf("%d - ");
    }
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        return Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Prblem reading your style defaulting to normal");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

para los tres parámetros.
para que no se quede el estilo debes de poner `[0m`.

por ejemplo con

```
private static void printStyledText(int font, int style, int background, String text) {
    System.out.printf("\033[%d;%d;%dm%s\n", font, style, background, text);
    System.out.print("\033[0m");
}
```

Si después de esto no te has aburrido, lo siguiente que puedes hacer es leer la imágen que tengas guardada y almacenarla en un `ImageIcon`.

En el imageIcon la redimensionas al tamaño de la consola o el área que pienses mostrar, por alguna razón lo normal es tener 80 caracteres de ancho, pero tendrás que experimentar porque la consola de replit es redimensionable.
Después de eso puedes usar la clase `FontMetrics` para obtener las dimensiones que tienes en pantalla para pintar tu imágen.

Luego debes de rescalar tu imágen de tal manera que queden los píxeles de ancho conforme a los caracteres que puedes mostrar horizontalmente, para eso es que elegimos ImageIcon; puedes elegir entre varios algoritmos para evitar pérdida de datos al reescalar.

Teniendolo en ImageIcon puedes fácilmente aplicar todas las transformaciones afines, no solamente el reescalado.

Finalmente exporta ti ImageIcon a una variable de tipo Image para poder obtener el arreglo o arreglos de bits que contiene la imágen, un arreglo de tamaño [filas][columnas] si es blanco y negro o [filas][columnas][3] si usas rgb, etc.

recorre los arreglos y pinta caracter por caracter usando los métodos antes mencionados para pintar a color en la consola, deberás de convertir los colores del espacio de color elegido a los colores de la paleta ansi, si usas 4 bits recuerda que empiezan desde 30, los colores de fondo empiezan desde 40 y se van alternando cada 10 obviamente; si en cambio prefieres de 8 bits tendrás una gama de 256 colores que estarán arreglados algo así:

```
0x00-0x07:  colores normales
0x08-0x0F:  colores intensos
0x10-0xE7:  cubo de 6 × 6 × 6 (216 colores)
0xE8-0xFF:  Escala de grises en 24 pasos
```

Respecto a que caracter usar para imprimir depende de la forma que le quieras dar a tu imágen, puedes usar cualquiera pero parecería ASCII art, mi recomendación es la de usar el caracter de rectángulo lleno.

Que te diviertas!

Comment: muchas gracias si estaré implementarlo he logrado hacer lo que mencionaste, crear una copia del programa pero si repetí el código, muchas gracias estaré buscando la solución!

Comment: Aunque la idea de Ruslan  es curiosa no creo que sea el camino correcto para Alfonso, ya que diríamos que cada pixel en la consola seria rellenar el rectángulo que contiene cada letra lo cual mostraría una imagen deformada y excesivamente grande además de un nivel de complejidad mucho mas alto al nivel que presenta Alfonso , lo mejor es que Alfonso aclare con su maestro el camino a seguir.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran estás asumiendo de más, especialmente en la parte del maestro

Comment: Muchas gracias igualmente ambos siempre es bienvenida una mano amiga, estaré preguntando mucho mas pero me ayudaron mucho a orientarme gracias!

Comment: @RuslanLópez mi punto es que intentar pintar una imagen utilizando los colores de la consola siendo que el esquema de color ni es RGB es una asunción mayor.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran yo nunca asumí el espacio de color rgb de la imágen, ni si tenía o no compresión. Por eso puse `un arreglo de tamaño [filas][columnas] si es blanco y negro o [filas][columnas][3] si usas rgb, etc.`. Respecto a que el esquema de colores de la consola justo ´puse los valores para que él experimente, hasta ahora solo he probado con los de 16 bits y funcionan de maravilla. Como también mencioné en la respuesta `La consola de repl.it es parcialmente compatible con xterm` énfasis en parcialmente.

Comment: @RuslanLópez no digo que tu Código plantee usar RGB sino que al convertir la imagen a un array para girarlo tendrá un esquema de color RGB por pixel, teniendo en cuenta que la pregunta plantea imprimir una imagen y girarla 180º, al utilizar ANSI estaría limitada a 256 colores en XTERM con lo cual ya seria una limitación importante para traducir el color a uno equivalente que soporte la consola, además  cada pixel seria representado por un espacio rectangular en vez de uno cuadrado perdiendo la forma, en eso me basaba para decir que imprimir en la Terminal debe de ser una confusion de Alfonso.